# Character Set Conversion Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

## Context

I have some python code which I am using to read the metadata from a video file using [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html). I am running the [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) command as a subprocess, collecting the stdout (which is in JSON format), then converting it to a python dictionary. The code looks something like this:

```
query = FFprobeQuery()
stdout, stderr = query.run(video)
```

This is running an [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) command as a subprocess call. The ffprobe command is:

```
ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams "video.mov"
```

The stdout is:

```
"streams": [
    {
        "index": 0,
        "codec_name": "h264",
        "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
        "codec_type": "video",
        "codec_time_base": "1/2000000",
        "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
        "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
        "width": 960,
        "height": 540,
        "has_b_frames": 0,
        "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
        "level": 31,
        "is_avc": "1",
        "nal_length_size": "4",
        "r_frame_rate": "1000000/41667",
        "avg_frame_rate": "55000000/2291667",
        "time_base": "1/1000000",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "2.291667",
        "bit_rate": "2090617",
        "nb_frames": "55",
        "tags": {
            "creation_time": "2013-11-04 09:38:31",
            "language": "eng",
            "handler_name": "Apple ╠µ╔Ý╩²¥¦┤ª└Ý│╠ð‗"
        }
    }
]
```

Then I convert the above string (stdout) to a python dictionary using the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) package:

```
video_data = json.loads(stdout)
```

## Error

The process described above usually works fine but in this case a `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised by the `json.loads(stdout)` call. I haven't included the entire stack trace here but the error looks something like this.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

It is important to note that in this particular case, the video file has been sent from China so I am guessing there are characters in the stdout string which are causing the error raised by the `json.loads(stdout)` call. My guess is the handler name value of `Apple ╠µ╔Ý╩²¥¦┤ª└Ý│╠ð‗`.

## Solution

My theory was that the stdout string needed to be converted from some Chinese codec to some other codec. After poking around a little I discovered that following code (converting stdout from `GB2312` to `ascii` using [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)) actually works:

```
import json
import chardet

detection = chardet.detect(stdout)
encoding = detection.get('encoding')
decoded_stdout = stdout.decode(encoding)

video_data = json.loads(decoded_stdout)
```

## Questions

I know nothing about character sets so I am trying to:

**1.** Determine whether I have taken the correct approach?

**2.** Understand why the conversion code I have written actually works?

**3.** Determine whether the issue can be solved using the standard python library?

All comments are much appreciated.

Comment: First, read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @ Peter DeGlopper. Very informative! Thanks! I will always endeavour to include a Content-Type definition or some other kind of tag describing the character set encoding for text based data.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a clarification: your approach doesn't convert from `GB2312` to ASCII - and nor would you want it to, since ASCII can't represent the string `'╠µ╔Ý╩²¥¦┤ª└Ý│╠ð‗'`. What `decode` returns is a sequence of abstract characters that can't be directly represented on disk - the encoding is a serialisation rule. This type is called `unicode` in Python 2 and `str` in Python 3; the type of `stdout` will be `str` in Python 2, and `bytes` in Python 3.

Passing raw bytes into `json.loads` tries to deserialise (decode) the input into a character string using utf-8. This gives the error you see since your input is serialised using a different, incompatible, encoding. Decoding it yourself first is the right approach - and in newer versions of Python, `json.loads` requires you to do this anyway (it strictly wants a character sequence rather than a byte sequence).

There is one caveat: guessing the encoding, the way chardet does, is *hard*, and potentially error prone. It happens to work in this particular case, but you have no guarantee that it will work if you need to do something similar with other files. It *may* be the best approach available to you - usually, you would expect to see the encoding mentioned early in the file's metadata, but it doesn't seem to be in this case. But you should always try to find some authoritative information on it before resorting to guesswork.

Comment: @ Ivc. Thanks! This is great! I'm not sure I understand all of what you have just said but I think I have extracted some useful stuff. It seems the real problem is that the source data doesn't contain the encoding information required to parse it correctly. Hence, I am forced to guess the encoding. As it stands, it seems my solution is a necessary evil.

Comment: I am a bit unsure about the clarification part of your response but perhaps I left out some crucial information. The abstract characters you refer to are output by the ffprobe command but once captured as  stdout, they actually look like this: `Apple \xcc\xe6\xc9\xed\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd\xb4\xa6\xc0\xed\xb3\xcc\xd0\xf2`. In other words, the stdout is of type `str`. When I use chardet to detect the encoding of this string, it returns  `GB2312` and when I use `str.decode("GB2312")` I get an `ascii` encoding. Can you please explain the first part of your response again?

Comment: @Yani check `type(stdout)` and `type(stdout.decode("GB2312"))` - they should be different. If you've read the article linked to under the question, then it should make sense that Py2 `unicode`/Py3 `str` is a sequence of unencoded unicode codepoints, while Py2 `str`/Py3 `bytes` is a sequence of raw bytes. `decode` doesn't *change* the encoding (to ASCII), it *removes* it (giving a sequence of codepoints, rather than bytes). This situation is a bit clearer in Python 3 than Python 2, because of the better type names, and other improvements. Consider upgrading if you can.